# Weird redirect between 2 subdomains

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to update my `.htaccess` as follows...

old url: `http://piesyearly.com/`

new url: `http://yearly.pies.com/`

these both live in the following file structure:

```
/public_html
htaccess.txt
../domains
../../piesyearly -->piesyearly.com
../yearlysubdomain -->yearly.pies.com
```

i've tried adding this to `header.php` of the old site, but it redirected every link to the homepage and not it's respective path at the new domain:

```
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://yearly.pies.com");
```

i've tried to modify my `htaccess.txt` as well, but nothing changed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^piesyearly\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://yearly.pies.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

obviously very confused here.

Comment: @anubhava the redirect 1/2 worked. it sent me to the new url, but it says the page cannot be found because the DNS lookup failed.

Comment: DNS lookup cannot be solved by rewrite rules. `yearly.pies.com` has to be a valid domain

Answer (score 1):

if the sub-paths on the two sites are identical, then simply do this at the Apache level:

```
RedirectPermanent / http://yearly.pies.com/
```

Sub-urls will be properly sent over to the identical suburl on the new domain name. No need for any rewriting, since it's a basic/simple 1:1 mapping.

Comment: I just pasted that into my `htaccess` but it's still loading the original url. Sorry if I'm missing something basic, I've never done this before.